# Traversing through a Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having trouble implementing a method to retrieve the information in a node given its location. For example, a location of 1 would return the head. A location of 2 would return the node just before the head.

```
if (location ==1)
    return top();
else 
    for (int i =1; i < LinkedStack.size(); i++){
        return LLNode.getInfo(location);
    }

return null;
```

^Thats what I have but its completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the list so do something like:

```
current = top();
for (int i = 1; i < location ; i++){
    current = current.next;
}
return current;
```

you may also want to add an if statement so if the location is larger than the list than return a message or something